# MSVC2012 Qt supposed to include a directory?

Tags: c++, qt, include, qtwidgets, qapplication

I built a custom Qt5 for msvc2012 using BlueGo.

I was reading the examples and they show this:

```
#include <QtGui>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     QApplication app(argc, argv);
     QWidget window;
     window.resize(320, 240);
     window.show();
     window.setWindowTitle(
         QApplication::translate("toplevel", "Top-level widget"));
     return app.exec();
 }
```

Problem is, QtGui for me is actually a directory and not a file so it cannot be included. I'm using the include files under /qtbase/include/. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QtGui header actually exists and simply includes all headers from the QtGui module. You can find it *inside* the QtGui directory. The compiler is able to find it because the QtGui directory is specified in the include paths. In other words, it's the same as:

```
#include <QtGui/QtGui>
```

It's a terrible practice to include the QtGui header though. You should only include what you actually use, otherwise compilation times will increase for no good reason. However, for quick tests and such, it's quite handy.

Comment: Hmm... even though the file doesn't look like its there I added that line and intellisense started scanning 400'ish files. Looks like something worked. I compile and get alot of lines like this though: `1>c:\users\...\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\qttest\qttest\main.cpp(5): error C2079: 'app' uses undefined class 'QApplication'` looks like it's not working as intended.

Comment: Update, I'm silly. QtGui doesn't have an extension so it isn't shown in Visual Studio. I include it and all the classes get highlighted and appear in intellisense, but their methods don't seem to be defined, throwing errors like those above.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late time now but you can do it like this:

add the `gui` module and `widgets` in the pro file :

```
QT += widgets core  gui
```

And by replaging the include files,

replace

```cpp
#include <QtGui/QWidget>
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
```

with

```cpp
#include <QWidget>
#include <QApplication>
```

The compiler should recognize it.